# Why map/reduce is used instead of for

Tags: javascript

I would like to know what are the benefits of using map/reduce instead of for vs foreach when we need to modified a given array. I have found out that a lot of people actually suggesting to use map/reduce.

I have did a testing and it turns out that using for the execution is actually at least 2-3x faster than using map/reduce consistently.

Is it because the benefits of chaining/code clarity of `map/reduce` outweigh the performance or is there any solid reason to use map/reduce instead of for loop.

[JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/fastest-array-loops-in-javascript/335) here showing on the result.

Comment: It's more declarative and alings better with the concepts of functional programming, which is gaining a lot of popularity these days.

Comment: @plalx Gaining a lot of popularity doesnt make a solid reason why map/reduce is preferred than for loop. I asked this question because i didnt see any post that really justify the reason of using map/reduce as people who suggest the use of map/reduce often ignores to discuss the slow execution time of it as compared to for loop. Justifying as better expressiveness/code readability alone and ignoring to discussing on the performance is considered as purely opinionated.

Comment: Now you can google why it's gaining popularity ;) Regarding performance, even if the difference would be in orders of magnitude, it doesn't matter if it's not practically noticeable. You shouldn't sacrifice readability for premature optimizations.